# pandas select rows by condition for all of dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3' : [5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
    col1    col2    col3
0      1       3       5
1      2       4       6
```

for example, i need select all rows with value = 1 so my code is:

```
df[df['col1']==1]
  col1  col2    col3
0    1     3       5
```

but how i can choose not only 'col1' but **all columns**, i have try this code:

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(df[df[col]==1])
```

but outpus not in pandas dataframe's view:

```
   col1  col2  col3
 0    1     3     5
        Empty DataFrame
        Columns: [col1, col2, col3]
        Index: []
        Empty DataFrame
        Columns: [col1, col2, col3]
        Index: []
```

can i go over all the columns and get view like in dataframe?

Comment: Do you want to condition on two or more columns? something like this:
`df[df['col1']==1][df['col2']==3]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`df.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) to check if any value in the df is equal to 1 and using [`df.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) on `axis=1` , this will return True for all rows where any of the column values have 1. Finally use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
output = df[df.eq(1).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: great! do you know how `.any` works with `.str.contains`? i need to search part of value in strings.

Comment: @germanjke `df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('dummy_string').any(axis=1)]` ?

Comment: thank you very much, its true, but you forgot one more parenthesis after `('dummy_string')` to close labmda function so this will be
`df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('dummy_string')).any(axis=1)]`